# Vim slows down over time with syntax on

Tags: syntax-highlighting, performance

Is there anything I can do to keep `syntax on` when using Vim?

As soon as I open anything substantial it becomes nearly impossible to edit after a while. Every keypress causes a delay. If I turn syntax highlighting off or relaunch vim – it is fine again.

I have `synmaxcol` set to 120. Sample ruby file is only 59 lines long and not exceeding 80 characters.

I am using `vim-ruby` and `vim-rails`.

The problem is that the delay seem to accumulate over time. When I open the file from scratch it is fine. After a while it gets slower and slower.

Comment: Have you tried replicating this with `vim -Nu NONE -c 'syntax on'`? Have you followed the debugging tips on this [post](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/246)

Comment: What filetype? Any?

Comment: Ruby. Indeed it is editable with `-u NONE` so it must be some plugin then. Guess the answer to most questions is 'disable plugins until you find the culprit' :(

Comment: But the problem is - the delay seems to accumulate over time. When I open the file from scratch it is fine. After a while it gets slower and slower.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Recent Vim versions have a `:syntime` command to troubleshoot slowness of syntax highlighting by generating a report of how long each syntax group takes to match. This is very helpful and quickly lets you find the culprit; the only downside is that you need a (usually "HUGE") build of Vim with profiling enabled. `:help :syntime` provides good instructions how to employ it.

Alternatively, you can try removing individual syntax scripts from `~/.vim/syntax/` and `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/` (according to the current `'filetype'`), and then further drill down by removing parts of the syntax definitions inside the script.

Comment: Hmm interesting, sounds like this is something tags related. The top line that takes the most time has methods from my other projects. 

`TOTAL      COUNT  MATCH   SLOWEST     AVERAGE   NAME               PATTERN
  0.129674   247    182     0.002365    0.000525  rubyMethodNameTag  \C\<\%(roi\|paginate\|admin_index_attributes\|facilities\|manager\|net_price?\ ....` – this is clearly from the other folder. Disable tags?

Comment: Do you use a plugin that highlights tags, such as _vim-easytags_? That might indeed cause the slowdown.

Comment: Yep, disabled it, not the numbers are sane again. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm now it's acting up again, this time its: `0.121880   2078   54      0.002260    0.000059  rubySymbol         []})\"':]\@<!\%(\h\|[^\x00-\x7F]\)\%(\w\|[^\x00-\x7F]\)*[!?]\=:[[:space:],]\@=
  ` – Anything I can do about it?

Comment: It might be the new regexp engine; try `:set regexpengine=1` (best in a new Vim instance, before opening the Ruby file).

Comment: I'll add it to `.vimrc` and see if it is going to change anything

Answer (score 7):

Another typical bottleneck in vim's syntax highlight is folding. Editing can become very slow if a fold contains many syntax items (which basically means it goes over many lines), because vim will refresh all syntax for every inserted character.

If this is what you are experiencing then I suggest the use of [FastFold](https://github.com/Konfekt/FastFold) plugin. This plugin identifies syntax folds and replaces them with manual folds, making vim's syntax highlight much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in the end:

- Removed `xolox/vim-easytags`
- Removed `xolox/vim-misc`
- Replaced
  `kien/ctrlp` `d11wtq/ctrlp_bdelete` and `tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky` with
  `junegunn/fzf`
- Set `regexpengine=1`

Right now Vim is smooth like butter but I don't have tags anymore. Sigh...

Comment: Vim has tags support built-in. You don't need any third-party plugins (other than ctags to generate the tags file of course). [See Effortless Ctags With Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) article by Tim Pope. I use this and it works wonders. Also see `:help tag-commands` to jump to a tag. I consider ctags pretty essential when working with Vim. It makes navigation super simple, and you can even autocomplete with `:help i_Ctrl-x_Ctrl-]`!

Comment: Care to add anything here http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-to-set-up-tags-properly/ ?